# Can I ORDER my results using a column returned from a subquery within a SELECT clause?

Tags: mysql

Using the example below, which is not the exact code, just an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

The query will be used to return the five most visited pages, by how many visits that page has registered.

```
SELECT
     page_instance.name AS 'page name',

     /* Sub Query I wish to sort by */
     (
       SELECT COUNT(*) 
       FROM visitor_event 
       WHERE page_instance.id = visitor_event.item_id
     ) AS 'visit count'

    FROM item_event

    LEFT JOIN visitor_event_type ON visitor_event_type.id =  visitor_event_type_id
    LEFT JOIN page_instance ON page_instance.id = visitor_event.item_id
    LEFT JOIN page ON page.id = page_instance.page_id

    WHERE visitor_event_type.handle = 'viewed'
    AND page_instance.name != 'NULL'
    GROUP BY page.id
    ORDER BY 'visit count' DESC /* Where its going wrong */
    LIMIT 5
```

Currently, the query runs without errors, but will not sort by the 'visit count' column.

*I've seen similar queries that put the subquery in the FROM clause. I don't understand the reasoning for this, as I might want to have other subqueries (for max / min results etc) for other columns. I'm not against the idea, I just don't understand the WHY of it*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
SELECT temp.* FROM (SELECT
     page_instance.name AS 'page name',
    (
       SELECT COUNT(*) 
       FROM visitor_event 
       WHERE page_instance.id = visitor_event.item_id
     ) AS 'visit_count'

    FROM item_event

    LEFT JOIN visitor_event_type ON visitor_event_type.id =  visitor_event_type_id
    LEFT JOIN page_instance ON page_instance.id = visitor_event.item_id
    LEFT JOIN page ON page.id = page_instance.page_id

    WHERE visitor_event_type.handle = 'viewed'
    AND page_instance.name != 'NULL'
    GROUP BY page.id
    LIMIT 5 ) as temp ORDER BY temp.visit_count DESC
```

Comment: Mind = blown. That was fast. Thanks. I can't actually accept this answer for another 9 minutes.